# command/syscall to find the peer IP used by a pointopoint interface (VPN)

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, l2tp

What [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) or command could I use to find the remote peer IP of an active tunnel on a [*nix system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like)

When Connecting to a VPN either l2tp/openvpn [ppp0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) or [tun/tap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) the user specify the remote IP or an app does this by default, doing ifconfig gives this info:

```
ppp0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
        inet 10.10.1.2 --> 10.10.1.1 netmask 0xff000000
```

or

```
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.22.151 --> 172.21.22.151 netmask 0xfffffe00
```

But having root privileges what command / syscall could be used to find  the remote/peer IP used by the tunnel.

Currently I am using [ifconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig), [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) but need to do many checks and compare output, therefore wondering what syscalls I or set of commands I could use in order create a script/code to automate this process.

When all traffic is routed through the tunnel using this helps:

```
$ netstat -rn  | grep -i 192.168.1.1
default            192.168.1.1        UGScI          22        0     en1
178.142.189.92     192.168.1.1        UGHS            4     3530     en1
192.168.1.1/32     link#4             UCS             2        0     en1
```

Assuming `192.168.1.1` is the current gateway I found that `178.142.189.92` is the peer IP.

But would like to know if is an easy way to basically find the `Destination` of the default gateway

Any ideas?